# "Special" characters in ms access regarding search

Tags: sql, ms-access

Does the . (period) have any special meaning in ms access when search?

For example, I have a table with 2 columns. (FETT Elements and FETT search)

One of the FETT elements is called "Essa T4" and FETT search is "Essa*HT4", I would like to make the "Essa*HT4" as "Essa*.HT4" however my searching doesn't come up as expected.

Does the dot notation have a special meaning in ms access?

thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier if you'd post your SQL. I expect the problem is with the asterisk, since that's one of the two wildcard characters. But it will be easier to diagnose if we see what you're trying and you tell us the results you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the period is not a wild-card.

As indicated [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP051881851033.aspx), the only ones you have to worry about are: *, ?, [], !, -, #, %, ^, _, and -.

Typically you would use them as part of a "like" comparison rather than "=".